# Visual Studio 2015 does not find System.Windows.Interactivity

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

Last week I've updated my windows from 8.1 to 10 and my Visual Studio from 2013 Ultimate to Enterprise 2015.

Yesterday I've implemented Load Tests via a `Web Performance and Load Test Project`. At this point I'd like to add an `ILoadTestPlugin` via the "Add Load Test Plug-In" option.

This does not work, as Visual Studio tells me it cannot find `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly.

As this also happens in my Visual Studio 2013 installation, I think the problem is not Visual Studio 2015 related.

[image]

As the error comes from the Visual Studio IDE as an Visual Studio internal error, this is not a duplicate of "how to add `System.Windows.Interactivity` to my solution!